# Looping out items in an array

Tags: lua

I'm new to Lua and I have a problem with printing out values of an array.

After googling I have come to this, but it only prints the last item in the array, `'armor'`. What am I doing wrong? Also how could I add a comma after every item?

```
local items = {'bread', 'shield', 'boots', 'legs', 'armor'}

for i, item in ipairs(items) do
    text = item
end

William:Speak("I am interested in the following: ".. text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing after the text is set to bread, shield, boots, legs, and then armor. This is why you only see "armor". You are iterating correctly but if you want to list all of them do this...

```
local items = {'bread', 'shield', 'boots', 'legs', 'armor'}

for i, item in ipairs(items) do
    text = item
    William:speak("I am interested in the following: ".. text)
end
```

This makes him speak every time you go through the for loop.

If you want them in a single string try this...

```
local items = {'bread', 'shield', 'boots', 'legs', 'armor'}

for i, item in ipairs(items) do
    text = text .. item
end
William:speak("I am interested in the following: ".. text)
```

I haven't tested this but it might solve your problem

```
local items = {'bread', 'shield', 'boots', 'legs', 'armor'}

for i, item in ipairs(items) do
    if item == items.length - 1 then
        text = text .. item
    else
        text = text .. item .. ", "
    end
end
William:speak("I am interested in the following: ".. text)
```

Comment: I think he wanted to print all of the items in a concatenated way. So `text = text .. item` would be the way to go I guess.

Comment: yes @thwiegan you are correct, that worked perfect now all i need to figure out is printing a comma and a space after every item except last. thanks guys i will accept your answer when i can snifferdog

Comment: snifferdog, for me 'text = item .. item' prints the last item two times but thwiegans 'text = text .. item' works, if i add 'local text = ""' before

Comment: @Snifferdog, there is still a mistake. I think it should be `text = text .. item` instead of `text = item .. item`. @Bolter was faster :D

Comment: ^ Good catch, I fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

A shorter way to do the concatenation with comma could also be ([source](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin)):

```
local items = {'bread', 'shield', 'boots', 'legs', 'armor'}
conc = table.concat(items, ",")

William:speak("I am interested in the following: ".. conc)
```